# Ember.js: Accessing ApplicationController methods in rendered template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using Ember.js and having an issue accessing methods from my ApplicationController in a rendered template partial.

In my layout i have the following

```
<div>
   {{ render common/navigation }}
   {{ outlet }}
</div>
```

in my application controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  isAuthenticated: function(){
    return true
  }.property()
});
```

and inside of common/navigation hbs template:

```
{{#if isAuthenticated}}
  <a href="#" {{action 'logout'}}>Logout</a>
{{/if}}
```

The problem is that isAuthenticated is never coming back as true

My assumption, which I think might be the issue, is that methods in ApplicationController are available to all templates - is this wrong?

How can I access isAuthenticated from the common/navigation template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my own issue,  I was losing scope by using {{render}}

In my layout I switched from {{render}} to {{partial}}

```
<div>
  {{partial common/navigation}}
  {{output}}
</div>
```

and all is well.

From the ember.js docs - "{{partial}} does not change context or scope. It simply drops the given template into place with the current scope." http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/